# If a mapping $f:X \rightarrow S^4$ is not surjective, then it must be null-homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If a mapping $f:X \rightarrow S^4$ is not surjective, then it must be null-homotopic.

Why is this? I understand that if the map is surjective then it is not homotopic to the constant map because $S^4$ is not contractible. Can somebody explain this to me? Are there similiar situations for $S^2, S^3$ or $S^n$ for that matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f:X\to S^4$ is not surjective, it misses a point $p\in S^4$.  Since $S^4\setminus\{p\}\cong\mathbb R^4$ is contractible, the result follows.

Also, you state that a surjective map is not nulhomotopic, but this is not necessarily true.  Let $f:\mathbb R^4\to S^4\setminus\{p\}$ be a stereographic projection.  Take a small neighborhood $U$ of $p$, collapse this to a point via a map $g:S^4\to S^4$.  Then the map $g\circ f:\mathbb R^4\to S^4$ is surjective, but also nulhomotopic, as $\mathbb R^4$ is contractible.

Lastly, the same two-sentence proof shows that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, if $f:X\to S^n$ is not surjective, then $f$ is nulhomotopic.

Comment: What you showed me about a surjective map onto $S^4$ not needing to be nulhomotopic was fascinating. I just thought because the map was surjective, it's image is $S^4$ and $S^4$ isn't contractible so the result would have followed. Do you have any insights you'd like to give as to the flaw in my thinking? I see why I was wrong because of the composition of maps you gave, but wouldn't mind some more insight.

Man, Algebraic Topology is tricky stuff!

Comment: The problem seems to be that you think that if a space is not contractible, then any map onto that space is not nulhomotopic. A map being nulhomotopic depends on more than just the image and its domain.  Indeed, my example shows it depends on more than the image, and it can be modified to give an example of a surjective nulhomotopic map $S^4\to S^4$.

Comment: When you collapse the neighborhood $U$ of $p$ to a point, arn't those points in $U - \{p\}$ not in the image of $gf$?

Comment: No, because the image of $\mathbb R^4$ under $f$ is $S^4\setminus\{p\}$, so it hits $U\setminus\{p\}$

Comment: Yeah, but after $f$ doesn't $g$ take a neighborhood of the points around $p$ and collapse it to $p$?? So all those points in the neighborhood except $p$ are no longer in the image?

Comment: Here's why $g\circ f$ is surjective. If $x\in S^4$ is not $g(U)$, then the (unique) point in $g^{-1}(x)$ is not $p$, hence lies in the image of $f$, so $x$ is in the image of $g\circ f$.  If $x=g(U)$, then there is some $y\in U\setminus\{p\}$ with $g(y)=p$. Since $y\neq p$, it follows that $y$ is in the image of $f$, and therefore $x$ is in the image of $g\circ f$.

Answer (score 1):

You could generalise this to $f:X\to S^n$, since $S^n\cong\Bbb R^n\cup \{\infty\}$ via stereographic projection,  and $\Bbb R^n$ is contractible.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that $S^4-\{point\}$ is contractible as it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ (stereographic projection), compose $f$ with $H_t$ where $H_t$ is the retraction of $s^4-\{point\}$ to a  to a point.